# localhostのphpmyadminでsqlをインポートをしましたが、容量が大きくて読み込めませんでした。

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

インポートするデータを受信できませんでした。ファイル名が送信されていないか、ファイルサイズが PHP の設定で許可された最大値を超えています。

というコメントが出てインポートできませんでした。
php.iniで容量を変更しても解決できませんでした。
sqlのファイルサイズは10.3mbです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際のphp.ini編集差分と実行したコマンド例えばapacheの再起動を実施したかなどの情報をいただくことは可能ですか？またPHPやApacheのエラーログは確認することは可能ですか？

Comment: apacheは再起動していません。925行目max_file_uploads=20、770行目post_max_size=100M、memory_limit=128M、max_input_vars = 1000などは変更したほうがいいのでしょうか？

Comment: php.iniを変更した場合はApacheの場合は再起動を実行しないとphp.iniが反映されません。phpinfo()を利用してでまずは変更した内容が反映されているか確認できますか？修正するファイルですがpost_max_sizeだけで基本的には大丈夫なはずです。

Comment: post_max_sizeの変更に加え、upload_max_filesizeの変更を実施の上、Apacheの再起動をしましたら、無事アップロードできました。迅速にご返信いただき、ありがとうございました！

Comment: このサイトではQ&Aの形で皆さんの経験を共有していただくことを目的の一つにしています。コメントのやりとりで解決できた場合も「回答」の形で解決内容をご投稿くださるようにお願いします。ご自分の質問にご自身で回答することもできます。